# How to set git committer email by remote

Tags: git, github

We keep our icinga2 configuration in a git repository which is owned by the `icinga` user on the server.  We do all the maintenance for those config files as this user.  However, we'd like to distinguish who has committed the changes.  We setup a `.ssh/config` file like this:

```
Host github-user1
  HostName github.myhost.org
  User git
  IdentityFile /var/spool/icinga2/.ssh/user1_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes

 Host github-user2
  HostName github.myhost.org
  User git
  IdentityFile /var/spool/icinga2/.ssh/user2_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

That allows us to create different remotes:

```
sshuser1  git@github-user1:OurOrg/icingaconf.git (fetch)
sshuser1  git@github-user1:OurOrg/icingaconf.git (push)
sshuser2  git@github-user2:OurOrg/icingaconf.git (fetch)
sshuser2  git@github-user2:OurOrg/icingaconf.git (push)
```

However, the committer in github still shows as `icinga` because that's the email of the user we're committing as.

Is there a way we can commit using this single application ID but track to different committer email addresses?  I tried to find a `git config` option that tied email address to the remote path but didn't see any such option, only global or repository-specific.